# Coverity integration issues with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, coverity, coverity-prevent

On trying to integrate Coverity with Jenkins and setting up the Integrity manager instances on Jenkins, I see the following error being reported :

```
Connected successfully, but Coverity web services were not detected.
```

This appears to be the Ajax response for a non 200 response code from the CIM. Any ideas on how this could be resolved will be very helpful.

Also, no projects show up in the drop down when using the configured instance to configure coverity during a 'post build action' for a project. It may be possible that this is primarily because of no web services being detected. The CIM is accessible on the correct port and I am able to commit defects to the database. This leads me to think that this may not be an install issue. I have google'd about this and did not see this error being reported on any thread. Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: What version of the Jenkins plug-in are you running and what version of Coverity Connect have you installed?

Comment: @MarkRobinson Coverity plug-in is version 1.3.1 and Coverity Connect is 5.5. Just realized that CIM < 5.5 requires the plug-in to be 1.2.4. I can now connect to the CIM. Thanks for the pointer!